# Prevent legacy init script from being enabled in systemd

Tags: systemd

I am in the process of updating a .deb package from a legacy SysV-style init script to native systemd units. However, I'd like to leave the old init script in the package for now for users of other init systems. The service in question can be configured to run as multiple users on the system.

For the old init script, the administrator added the desired users to a specific group, and the init script took care of starting an instance of the service for each user. For systemd, I'd instead like to use a template to enabled separate instances for each user. E.g., `systemctl enable my-service@user1; systemctl enable my-service@user2`. This allows each user's instance to be started and stopped independantly, instead of all or nothing.

Normally, when a package has both a SysV-style init script and a systemd unit, they'll have the same name, so the native systemd unit will shadow the init script, ensuring systemd users use the systemd unit. In this case, however, since the new unit is a template, it does *not* shadow the init script. How can I prevent systemd users from enabling the init script, and instead guide them to the systemd service template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Debian, this is done by various services, e.g. `saned`:

- The SysVinit-style script is `/etc/init.d/saned`, which would normally cause `systemd-sysv-generator` to auto-generate `saned.service`.
- But the package disables this by providing a symbolic link `/lib/systemd/system/saned.service -> /dev/null`, which both blocks the autogeneration and causes `systemd` to regard `saned.service` as `masked`.
- In addition, the package provides its own template `/lib/systemd/system/saned@.service`. Any instances of this template are fully separate from the masked `saned.service` and work as normal.

In other words, to get what you want, you'll just need to package a symbolic link `/lib/systemd/system/my-service.service` pointing to `/dev/null`.